# Compare two strings and return bigger items in each - Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, compare

I have two equal-length strings, which are part of two lists `a` and `b`, they look like this:

```
a[1] = '0   8 9'
b[1] = '0 * 5 6'
```

I want to compare each items in each string above in order (by ASCII code), also for the rest of the list `a` and `b`.

My expect result for these 2 strings would be:

```
'0 * 8 9'
```

I'm new to Python, I have read about list comprehension but I don't know how to use that in this case. I need some help, thank you in advance!

EDIT: I have to compare non-numeric values. So I have to compare them by ASCII code. (I make some changes the questions)

Comment: How do you compare those strings by ASCII code?

Comment: Please read the edit, I have to compare the characters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
''.join(map(max, a, b))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = '0   8 9'
>>> b = '0 * 5 6'
>>> ''.join(map(max, a, b))
'0 * 8 9'
```

Answer (score 2):

***Note : below is in case of the requirements being for comparision of numbers only (before the OP's edit). For the OP's new requirements, check [@StefanPochmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48322111/7550472)***

Using `list comprehension` :

```
>>> [ max(map(int,ele)) for ele in zip(a.split(),b.split()) ]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : a  = '0 1 8 9' 
IN : b = '0 4 5 6'
OUT : [0, 4, 8, 9]
```

---

Next is easy. Just `join` them. So, finally :

```
>>> l = [ str(max(map(int,ele))) for ele in zip(a.split(),b.split()) ]   
>>> ' '.join(l)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : a  = '2 1 8 9'
IN : b = '11 4 5 6'
OUT : '11 4 8 9'
```

***IMP : The `map` here takes care of situations involving finding of `max` between numbers like `[2, 11]` , where without it, it would chose `2` (as its max in string chronological order)***

Comment: Thanks! I think the zip function can be used even in the character comparison case.